# Highlight polygon on mouse over in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I am doing a map on Leaflet and I would like to know how to put my polygons highlighted visually in some way when they are covered with a mouse a bit like that: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/basic/basic_Poly.html

I know you have to use the function `highlightFeature` but I can't use it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  map = L.map("map").setView([46.227638, 2.213749], 6);
  lControl = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

  fondPlan = L.tileLayer(
    "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
    {
      maxZoom: 17,
    }
  ).addTo(map);
  lControl.addBaseLayer(fondPlan, "Carte topo");

  fondSAT = L.tileLayer("http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}", {
    maxZoom: 17,
  }).addTo(map);
  lControl.addBaseLayer(fondSAT, "Carte Satellite");

  $.getJSON(
    "geojson/Muron.geojson",
    {},

    function (data) {
      vmuron = L.geoJSON(data, {
        style: function () {
          return {
            color: "#FF0000",
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.7,
          };
        },

        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          contenu =
            "<b>ID: </b>" +
            feature.properties.prefixe +
            feature.properties.section +
            feature.properties.numero +
            "<br>";
          contenu +=
            "<b>Surface: </b>" + feature.properties.contenance + " m² <br>";
          layer.bindTooltip(contenu, {
            permanent: false,
            sticky: false,
            opacity: 1,
            direction: "top",
          });
        },
      });

      vmuron.addTo(map);
      lControl.addOverlay(vmuron, "Muron");
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about "but I can't use it"? What does not work as expected? Is map displayed?  Is GeoJSON overlay displayed? Are there any errors in the debugger console? You can see official example of highlighting polygons at Leaflet site: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: Hi @Nanbar, did you get any progress on how to keep the vectors select instead of selecting them only when the mouse is over them?